# how to cache loaded html with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript function that loads some html from the server:

```
function addPerson(){
    var p = $('<div>').load('data/person.php',function(){
        //set click and key actions

        $('#element').append($(this));
    });

    return p;
}
```

and I want to have another function that will load some data into the elements after adding them so if the user is coming back:

```
function loadPerson(){
    var ep = addPerson();
    ep.find('#txtName').val('My Name');
    //and so on
}
```

but the loadPerson never fills in any of the info. I debugged in fireant and realized that the value of ep is always an empty div which made me realize the element is being cached before the asynchronous query finishes. Any idea on how to return the element completely loaded?

P.S. I need both functions!

EDIT:

I have also tried this without luck:

```
function addPerson(){
    var p;
    $('<div>').load('data/person.php',function(){
        //set click and key actions

        $('#element').append($(this));
        p = $(this);
    });

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Because it is an asynchronous call! Load fires after you try to find the element that still has not been loaded. Use callbacks!

Comment: I thought I was doing that

Comment: Look at the jquery docs for promise http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pattern I use in my projects,

**`Code:`**

```
(function($) {
   var foo = {
       init: function() {
           this.someObject = null;
           this.cache();
           return this; // to allow chaining
       },
       cache: function() {
          this.someObject = $(".someClass");
       }
   };

   window.load = foo.init();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think we're talking about different load functions. The one I am asking about loads html content form a file on the server....

Comment: Does it matter what you load to cache?